# How to dowhile loop in camel context with expression containing sql query?

Tags: apache-camel

Wanted to add some portion of route in loop so that it executes again and again till the sql query returns some value. And loop must end if no data is returned by sql query.

Answer (score 0):

its a example about sql it is not good scenario but you can change it for yourself

CamelSqlRowCount = The number of rows returned for select operations, returned as an Integer object. This header is not provided when using outputType=StreamList.

```
   from("direct:start")
            .loopDoWhile(simple("${headers.CamelSqlRowCount} <= 5"))
                .to("mock:loop")
                .to('sql:select * from student where id=1')
            .end() // end loop
            .to("mock:result");
```